# SQL query to get the first date, depending on the current group (~control break)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a sql query which returns the first date of the current group.

Let's assume (just as an example) that on the first of every month a row is saved in a table (EmployeeInfo) with the employee ID and the current department.

```
EmployeeID, Department, Date (Format: DD.MM.YYYY)
100, IT, 01.07.2014
100, IT, 01.08.2014
100, IT, 01.09.2014
100, HR, 01.10.2014
100, HR, 01.11.2014
100, CC, 01.12.2014
100, IT, 01.01.2015
100, IT, 01.02.2015
100, IT, 01.03.2015
100, IT, 01.04.2015
```

The query should return the date since an employee is working in the current department.

The current department of the employee with ID 100 is IT, therefore the value should be 01.01.2015 (not 01.07.2014).

Any ideas how this could be implemented?

Comment: Shouldn't the value `01.02.2015` ??

Comment: No, the value shoud definitely be 01.01.2015. The expected value is the date since an employee is working in the current department.

Comment: How come `01.01.2015` you want the latest value for the date by that `01.02.2015` is the latest.

Comment: I want the first date of a group, not the latest. As described, "The query should return the date since an employee is working in the current department."

Comment: By that standard it should be `01.07.2014` when employee started working isn't it ?

Comment: No, as explained in the example, the result should be 01.01.2015. I'm interested in the date since someone is working for the current department (doesn't matter if the employee has been working for the department before).

Comment: Use `ANALYTIC` **LAG**. See my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** New answer based on OP's comments.

You could use **ANALYTIC** function `ROW_NUMBER` and `LAG`.Something like, start of group method:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 100 EmployeeID, 'IT' Department, to_date('01.07.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 100, 'IT', to_date('01.08.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  4  select 100, 'IT', to_date('01.09.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  5  SELECT 100, 'HR', to_date('01.10.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  6  select 100, 'HR', to_date('01.11.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  7  SELECT 100, 'CC', to_date('01.12.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  8  select 100, 'IT', to_date('01.01.2015','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  9  select 100, 'IT', to_date('01.02.2015','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual
 10  )
 11  SELECT EmployeeID,
 12    Department,
 13    DT
 14  FROM
 15    (SELECT *
 16    FROM
 17      (SELECT t.*,
 18        CASE
 19          WHEN Department = lag(Department) over (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY dt)
 20          THEN 0
 21          ELSE 1
 22        END gap
 23      FROM DATA t
 24      ) T
 25    WHERE GAP = 1
 26    ORDER BY DT DESC
 27    )
 28  WHERE ROWNUM = 1
 29  /

EMPLOYEEID DE DT
---------- -- ---------
       100 IT 01-JAN-15

SQL>
```

**OLD answer**

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 100 EmployeeID, 'IT' Department, to_date('01.07.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 100, 'IT', to_date('01.08.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  4  select 100, 'IT', to_date('01.09.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  5  SELECT 100, 'HR', to_date('01.10.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  6  select 100, 'HR', to_date('01.11.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  7  SELECT 100, 'CC', to_date('01.12.2014','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  8  select 100, 'IT', to_date('01.01.2015','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual union all
  9  select 100, 'IT', to_date('01.02.2015','DD.MM.YYYY') dt from dual
 10  )
 11  SELECT*
 12  FROM
 13    (SELECT t.*,
 14      row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY department ORDER BY dt DESC) rn
 15    FROM DATA t
 16    )
 17  WHERE rn = 1
 18  /

EMPLOYEEID DE DT                RN
---------- -- --------- ----------
       100 CC 01-DEC-14          1
       100 HR 01-NOV-14          1
       100 IT 01-FEB-15          1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately, the result is wrong - the query returns 01-FEB-15, the expected value is 01-JAN-15.

Comment: Just remove the `desc` from order by clause and you should get what you want.

Comment: No, that doesn't solve my problem. That would return 01.07.2014 (01-JUL-14). As clearly stated and described, the expected value is 01.01.2015 (01-JAN-15).

Answer (score 0):

Use below query and let me know if want this

```
   WITH table_ (EmployeeID, Department, Dat) AS (
      SELECT 100, 'IT', TO_DATE('01.07.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 100, 'IT', TO_DATE('01.08.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 100, 'IT', TO_DATE('01.09.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 100, 'HR', TO_DATE('01.10.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 100, 'HR', TO_DATE('01.11.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 100, 'CC', TO_DATE('01.12.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 100, 'IT', TO_DATE('01.01.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 100, 'IT', TO_DATE('01.02.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL),
    ----------
    --End of Data preparation
    ----------
    table1 AS (SELECT EmployeeID, Department, Dat, 
                      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY dat DESC) -
                      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID, department ORDER BY dat DESC) rk
                 FROM TABLE_),
    table2 AS (SELECT EmployeeID, Department, Dat, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY dat) rnk
                 from table1
                WHERE rk = 0 )
    SELECT EmployeeID, Department, Dat
      FROM table2
     WHERE rnk = 1;
```

output:

```
EMPLOYEEID DE DAT
---------- -- ---------
       100 IT 01-JAN-15
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, the query isn't working as expected. It returns the last but one date. E.g. if there would be additional entries 100, IT, 01.03.2015 and 100, IT, 01.04.2015, the result would be 01.03.2015 (which is wrong, since it should be 01.01.2015)

Comment: You just need to use Analytic LAG, see my answer.

Comment: @theb I don't how you tested that, but I am getting correct answer even after adding the additional values as mentioned by you. Anyways, you got your answer, cheers :)

Comment: @San Yes, you are right, apologizes for that! Tested it again, and it works as expected. Thanks a lot!